# nestjs + graphql + typeorm, how to transform a lazy relation (promise) into solid array for the model

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, class-transformer

I am using nestjs with graphql (apollo) and typeorm. My entity has a lazy relation `roles` and the model represents it as an `array`. The issue is that it cannot seem to "magically" transform the Promise<[]> into []. Here's in more detail,

I have the **UserModel** which looks like this

```
@ObjectType({ description: 'User' })
export class UserModel {
  @Field()
  id: string;

  @Field(() => [UserRolesModel], { nullable: true })
  roles?: UserRolesModel[]
}
```

and the **UserEntity** which looks like that

```
@Entity({ name: 'user' })
export class UserEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @OneToMany(() => UserRolesEntity, (userRoles) => userRoles.userId)
  roles: Promise<UserRolesEntity[]>;
}
```

**typescript complains that** the Promise<UserRolesEntity[]> is not compatible with UserRolesModel[].

```
TS2322: Type 'UserEntity[]' is not assignable to type 'UserModel[]'.
Type 'UserEntity' is not assignable to type 'UserModel'.
Types of property 'roles' are incompatible.
Type 'Promise<UserRolesEntity[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'UserRolesModel[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more.
```

I suspect there is some trivial way of doing that with nestjs and the class-transformer?
What is the recommended way of solving this?

Comment: I think you cannot assign V to Promise<V> and vice versa, but `@Field` decorator from nestjs/graphql is not relying on typescript property type and you can use any type, e.g.
`@Field(() => [UserRolesModel], { nullable: true })
roles?: UserRolesModel[] | Promise<UserRolesModel[]>`
But it is still bad design, you should not assign entity to dto even if they have same shape (same properties). You should do map instead (e.g. by https://github.com/nartc/mapper)

Comment: @iamthes nest in the "background" uses ClassTransformer which practically does exactly that. I have tried using My short-term solution was to use `Promise<UserRolesModel>` in the field. If I cannot find the "magic" nestjs solution easy solution then the next best approach is to write a transformation for the ClassTransformer to perform the appropriate mapping. I am still certain there is some "magic" way of declaring it in nestjs with ClassTransformer to do it without having to create a transformer for the usecase.